# Plot Subset of Dataframe without Being Redundant

Tags: python, pandas, plot

a bit of a Python newb here. As a beginner it's easy to learn different functions and methods from training classes but it's another thing to learn how to "best" code in Python.

I have a simple scenario where I'm looking to plot a portion of a dataframe `spdf`. I only want to plot instances where `speed` is greater than 0 and use `datetime` as my X-axis. The way I've managed to get the job done seems awfully redundant to me:

```
ts = pd.Series(spdf[spdf['speed']>0]['speed'].values, index=spdf[spdf['speed']>0]['datetime'])

ts.dropna().plot(title='SP1 over Time')
```

Is there a better way to plot this data without specifying the subset of my dataframe twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a new Series. You can plot using your original `df`

```
df[df['col'] > 0]].plot()
```

In your case:

```
spdf[spdf['speed'] > 0].dropna().plot(title='SP1 over Time')
```

I'm not sure what your `spdf` object is or how it was created. If you'll often need to plot using the 'datetime' column you can set that to be the index of the `df`.If you're reading the data from a csv you can do this using the `parse_dates` keyword argument or it you already have the `df`you can change the index using `df.set_index('datetime')`. You can use `df.info()` to see what is currently being used at your index and its datatype.

Comment: OK that really helps, thanks. Setting an ad-hoc index (of sorts) definitely helps my current situation. So my plotting code is simply:

spdf.set_index('datetime').plot(y='speed')

Is their more advice in general you can give about using a subset of a dataframe for multiple operations and trying NOT to duplicate it? Naively I tried to do something like:
with spdf[spdf['speed']>0] as f:
...do something here...

Comment: @AustinT It's difficult to answer generally...If you need to carry about a number of difficult operations to your data, you could consider writing a function to do all the things you need done which takes a df or series as an argument. If you're just doing some initial exploration, you could consider setting the selection to a variable `mask = df[df['col'] > 0]]` (similar to your initial approach) which will save on typing. If you have a more specific example I'll try to give a better answer. Good luck!